# Sorting a queue of structures by different fields

Tags: c++, struct, queue

It seems like I can define an operator for a struct and use std::sort for the sorting - the issue I'm seeing with this is that it seems like I can only define one sorting method.  I'd like to define two others based on other fields.  Is it possible to define more?

Otherwise, the only other thing I can think of is to move the structures into a vector and sort the vector using functions defined for each sort.  I'm fine with handling it that way but I'm wondering if there is a more ideal way of handling sorting of structures in a queue by its fields.

For example, with this struct...

```
struct job
{
    int id;
    int start;
    int end;

    bool operator<(Process const &other) { return start < other.start; }
};

queue<jobSet>
```

I know I can set up a bool to sort by start...

```
sort(begin(jobSet), end(jobSet));
```

But I'm not sure how to set up another sort that works with the end field

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. My guess is you want to sort objects of a certain type differently depending on the context? You can pass your own comparator to `std::sort`, so that's easily achievable. You should clarify your question if this isn't what you want.

Comment: Ok I've added sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can define your custom comparer for sorting, i.e.

```
struct compareStart{
    bool operator<(Job const& a, Job const& b) { return a.start < b.start; }
}

struct compareEnd{
    bool operator<(Job const& a, Job const& b) { return a.end < b.end; }
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
sort(begin(jobSet), end(jobSet), compareStart());
sort(begin(jobSet), end(jobSet), compareEnd());
```

Or if you have c++11 use lambdas:

```
sort(begin(jobSet), end(jobSet), [](Job const& a, Job const& b) { return a.end < b.end; });
```

You do not have to use the comparisson oprator of the job object

Comment: Ah ok - I thought I had to work with the comparison operator.  This is helpful..thanks!!